# How to say that event is happening now?

Tags: meaning, verbs, idioms

Imagine if I sit in the classroom and I want to say that some lecture is going in another classroom. I what to express that meaning using active voice, like

- Lecture is happening now

But for me, it sounds too pathetic for an ordinary event. Can you give some hint on how to say that kind of thing?

Comment: What is wrong with _There is a lecture in the other classroom starting now_

Comment: "The lecture is *going on **right now***" has a stronger sense of urgency. "Professor Koval *is **currently speaking*** in the other room" is more descriptive.

Comment: [Related](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/21846/2303).

Comment: *"X"* is lecturing in room *Y* right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Occurring

"That/The lecture is occurring now."

> Happening

"That/The lecture is happening right now."

> Underway

"That/The lecture is already underway."

> Taking place

"That/The lecture is taking place right now."

> Started

"That/The lecture has already started."

> Begun

"That/The lecture has begun."

---

***Taking place*** is probably best.

Comment: Yes; though 'is occurring' and 'is happening' are not wrong, no one would ever use them without a good reason (eg to emphasise that this is the most important lecture since Darwin).

Answer (score 2):

A lot of good suggestions in the other answers.  You might also consider "ongoing."  Oxford dictionaries defines ongoing as follows:

> [ongoing](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/ongoing) - adj. - Continuing; still in progress

E.g. "The lecture is ongoing."

Answer (score 1):

Just because I'm surprised this wasn't suggested as an answer:

> In Progress

"That/The lecture is in progress."